# How to launch python in background mode

Tags: python, windows, hide

How can I hide my python program in this thing on Windows 10?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try saving your files using .pyw instead of .py. This way the terminal won't pop up but you still can see them using the Task Manager.

Comment: Thank you! But if i want to make like server on my pc how can i stop this programm ( if ill open it in .pyw file )?

Comment: To stop the program simply go in the Task Manager, go to your program and click Terminate Execution. N.B. .pyw files will stop if you turn off your computer completely. To have a program running 24/7 you either have to make it run on something like a raspberry pi or using something like https://www.pythonanywhere.com/